# CSS animation with delay and opacity

Tags: css, animation, opacity

I am trying to fade in an element after 2 sec using CSS animation. The code works great in new browsers, but in old browsers the element will stay hidden because of "opacity:0".

I want it to be visible in old browsers and I don't want to involve javascript. Can it be solved using CSS? Eg. some how target browsers that doesn't support animation?

**CSS:**

```
#element{
animation:1s ease 2s normal forwards 1 fadein;
-webkit-animation:1s ease 2s normal forwards 1 fadein;
opacity:0
}

@keyframes fadein{from{opacity:0}
to{opacity:1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{from{opacity:0}
to{opacity:1}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id=element>som content</div>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just don't set the initial `opacity` on the element itself, set it within the `@keyframes`:

```
#element{
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
    0% { opacity:0; }
    66% { opacity:0; }
    100% { opacity:1; }
}
```

This technique takes the delay off of the animation, so that it starts running immediately. However, the opacity won't really change until about 66% into the animation. Because the animation runs for 3 seconds, it gives the effect of a delay for 2 seconds and fade in for 1 second.

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/75mhnaLt/

You might also want to look at using conditional comments for older browsers; IE8 and IE9.

Something like the following in your **HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en-GB"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 ie-7" lang="en-GB"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 ie-8" lang="en-GB"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

You could then do something like:

```
.lt-ie9 #element {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Remove `opacity: 0` like @Michael Giovanni Pumo stated, however instead of time-stretching to merge the delay into the timeline, just apply `animation-fill-mode: backwards` to apply the delay to the first keyframe (aka the 'from' state).  Note: If your ending keyframe does something unique within the animation, then you will want to use `animation-fill-mode: both`.
https://jsfiddle.net/m3z2htLe/

Comment: With this approach animation easing effect won't be the same as intended, would it?

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem, where the requirement was to wait `n` seconds before fading in different page elements, one after another.

The key to getting this working for me, that isn't mentioned in any of the other answers, is the fact that `animation` can actually take a list of animations to run.  It will start running them simultaneously so you need to insert delays in order to run them sequentially.

My solution was this (in SCSS, but simple enough to write as straight CSS if you need):

```
@mixin fade-in($waitTime) {
    animation: 
        wait #{$waitTime},
        fade-in 800ms #{$waitTime};
}

@keyframes wait {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Usage:

```
h1 {
    @include fade-in('500ms');
}
h2 {
    @include fade-in('700ms');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you set the `opacity` of the element to 1 per default (for browsers that do not support animations). Then start the animation at 0s and use the keyframes to delay the animation.

```
#element{
animation:3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
-webkit-animation:3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
opacity:1
}

@keyframes fadein{
    0%{opacity:0}
    80%{opacity:0}
    100%{opacity:1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
    0%{opacity:0}
    80%{opacity:0}
    100%{opacity:1}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mg00t86v/2/

Answer (score 1):

Since all the major browsers [support CSS3 animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) with the notable exception of `IE<10` you could use conditional comments into your HTML like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><html class="lte-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

thus you can add a more specific rule for `IE<10` using the `.lte-ie9` classname in a specific selector

```
.lte-ie9 #element {
   opacity: 1;
   filter : alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I would not move instead the `opacity: 0` inside the first keyframe as a primary suggestion, since this would limit all the animations to have an `animation-delay` equal to `0` (or otherwise you could see a kind of *fouc* for the element itself)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this might be help you.

**HTML**

```
<div>some text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
-webkit-animation: fadein 5s linear 1 normal forwards;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes fadein{
from{
   opacity: 0;
}
to{
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This waits 3 seconds and then slides in from left:

EVEN SHORTER:

```
.myclass {animation: 4s slidein;}

@keyframes slidein {
0% {opacity:0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);}
92% {opacity:0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);}
100% {opacity:1;
    transform: translateX 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use `animation-delay` css property for delay:

```css
.delayed-fadeout {
  animation: 1s forwards fadeout;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
@keyframes fadeout {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Beware – `animation-delay` should go after `animation` since animation shorthand overwrites it.