# Using css to delay opacity transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, delay

How would I be able to delay an opacity transition using css?

How it works is, after the play image is clicked, then the transition effect begins.

What I want to do is delay the opacity transition using css, is there a way to do this?

I can't figure it out.

That's what I am trying to do.

```
.fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 3s;
}
 
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

  <div class="split-wrap fadeout">
```

Would this be done using a combination of javascript with css?

**Something like this?**

I wasn't able to get it to work

https://jsfiddle.net/tea2d0rq/

```
.delay{
 transition-delay: 5000s;
 transition-property: opacity;
}

 const fadeout = document.querySelector(".fadeout");
 fadeout.classList.add("delay");

<div class="split-wrap fadeout delay">
```

Below Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ap439zk/

```js
(function iife() {
  "use strict";

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    hide(cover);
    const curtain = document.querySelector(".curtain");
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
    const fadeout = document.querySelector(".fadeout");
    fadeout.classList.add("fade");
    const thewrap = curtain.parentElement.querySelector(".container");
    show(thewrap);
  }

  const cover = document.querySelectorAll('.jacketa');
  cover.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', coverClickHandler)
  });
}());
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
}

.fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 3s;
}
 
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curtain.slide {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.curtain.slide .panel-left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.curtain.slide .panel-right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.tcell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.jacketa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #130e85;
  border: 3px solid #f91f6e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 2px #f9066bf7;
   display: block !important;
}
.j1 .jacketa {
  left: 30px;
}

.j2 .jacketa {
  right: 30px;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.jacketa .coversvg {
  width: 70px;
  height: 75.4px;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .back {
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

.jacketa .coversvg .front {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear, flicker-1 2s linear 2s infinite both;
}

@keyframes draw {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flicker-1 {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  41.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  42% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  43.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  47.99% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  48% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  49.01% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.split-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 260px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 10s ease;

}

.j1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.j2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 10s ease;
}

.container {
  height: auto;
}

.curtain.slide .j1 {
 left: -50%;
}

.curtain.slide .j2 {
  left: 50%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="curtain ">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="tcell">

      <div class="container hide">
        <div class="container-top">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-left"> </div>
      <div class="panel-right"> </div>

      <div class="split-wrap fadeout">
        <div class="j1">
          <div class="jacketa" title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="j2  ">
          <div class="jacketa  " title="[ Enjoy The Music ]">
            <svg class="coversvg" width="70" height="75.4" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
              <title>[ Enjoy The Music ]</title>
              <path class="back" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
              <path class="front" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83" />
            </svg>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out this post with a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846224/css-animation-with-delay-and-opacity

Comment: Have you tried `transition: property name | duration | timing function | delay`

Comment: I'm using a transition and not animation.

Comment: @htmlcsscoding have you tried "transition-delay: {insert delay}" ?

Also check out the transition delay doc on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Comment: Yes, I have tried transition-delay, it doesn't work, it has no effect. Were you able to get it to work using that?

Comment: I tried https://jsfiddle.net/15k8wzvd/ .fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 3s;
  transition-delay: 8000s;
  transition-property: opacity;
} / It has no effect. Am I doing it wrong?